# ''Automatic culling'' of tags

Tags: discussion, tags

This concerns the [create new tags privilege](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) that comes with 1K reputation. In particular, an excerpt from the link reads:

> However, note that:
>
> on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.

What is not clear here is,

A) If I create a new tag, and use it for the question that I want to use it for, and be done with it. Neither I, nor anyone else uses it for 6 months.

B) I use it twice in my (original) questions, but no one else uses it for 6 months.

C) I use it once in a original question, then start to look for the other places where it can be used, and re-tag existing questions (which existed with some tags even before I created this new tag).

Surely, the tag would be culled in case A). But what about cases B and C?

**In particular, is case C) a legitimate way of bending around the rules?** I mean, will I invite anyone's wrath if I do it, or is it considered inappropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is okay to use your new tag on older questions, as long as you do not flood the main page in your retagging or apply the tag wrongly.

It might be worthwhile to ask in chat if the tag follows the tag rules before doing this though.

Comment: Or better still, incorporate this here itself, editing the question. Would that be fine?

Comment: I dunno, I think that might be changing the meaning of the question.

Comment: @DavidZ - yes you're right. I think, it constitutes a different purpose. But, does every time a guy creates a new tag, he seeks permission here on meta, or are there a set of objective rules that people are supposed to check for themselves?

Comment: @New_new_newbie no, nothing like that. Anyone with enough reputation can create a new tag when it's needed, i.e. when the existing tags don't cover it and you expect there to be multiple questions which the tag will usefully apply to. There's no need to get approval for every new tag.

Comment: @DavidZ - Thanks. But Manish says it is worthwhile to ask in chat beforehand. Discordance?

Comment: @New_new_newbie this is just in case the tag is a meta tag or a soft tag or something. Best not go on a retagging effort if it's going to be undone :) Asking in chat is not a hard rule, just a suggestion for until you get used to the types of tags we allow.

Comment: @Manishearth - OK. Can we do that right now?

Comment: @Manishearth - I've posted something in chat (I hope in the right place, it was my first chat post!). Please let me know if it is appropriate. (David probably has a different time zone).

Comment: @New_new_newbie if you plan on actually applying the tag to a bunch of old questions, or if it's a meta tag or some such thing, then you ask. But there's no need to ask simply to use a tag that doesn't already exist on a question you're asking. By the time you get 1k rep you should have the sense to only do that if it's necessary.

Comment: @DavidZ , Manish - Though I can sniff a sense of reluctance (also with Qmechanic's responses in chat), I think it is worthwhile to deem the response as affirmative. So, this meta post wasn't a bad idea, I've heard from three moderators now. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, what @DavidZ said. If you're going off on a retagging spree, ask first :) A single tagging is something easily undone so when you want to apply one on your question, shoot first and ask questions later ;)

Comment: Ok Thank you, both of you. And ''_shoot first ..._'', [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126533/46399) it is. :)

Comment: @New_new_newbie If there's a sense of reluctance, it's probably because the site has been up for several years now and *most* conceivably good tags have been implemented already, and new tags are correspondingly rather rare. Also, some "missing" tags used to exist but were intentionally merged in with others or done away with because they did more harm than good. So seeking a second opinion never hurts.

Comment: @ChrisWhite - Exactly, so apart from here, this was also taken up in chat where I've heard from Qmechanic and dmckee also. So, that's four opinions already :)